# How can I get Putty to support 256 colors in Emacs on CentOS?

Tags: linux, emacs, centos, putty

As far as I can tell from browsing around, I should be getting 256 colors in my Emacs, but I'm not.

I'm running CentOS 5.4 on an [ec2 instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). I'm running Putty 0.60 on Windows 7. Putty is set to send `xterm-256color` for its terminal string. Putty is set to allow 256 colors. On CentOS, my `$TERM` is set to `xterm-256color`.

`tput colors` shows 256. I recompiled Emacs to 23.2, making sure to install `libtermcap-devel` beforehand, because someone claimed they needed that. But still, when I `M-x list-colors-display` in Emacs, it only shows 8 colors.

Comment: What happens if you start `emacs` with `--colors=256`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As it happens, got it working a couple minutes after posting. I did two things, so it's one or the other: 1) Turned on global font lock and 2) ran an elisp script I found on emacswiki that "filled in" the color names or some dumb thing.

Comment: "Putty is set to send xterm-254color" is a typo, right? and you could also use .. vim :) /me pats his shiney 256-color-vim ...

Comment: @akira: It _should_ be 256, but no editor wars please.

Comment: mind to answer your own question and accept your own answer? that would close this open question :)

Answer (score 1):

The questioneer solved this:

1. Turn on global font lock.
2. Run an elisp script you can find on the emacswiki that "fills in" the color names, etc...